# Truncation in Emacs Powerline (mode line)

Tags: emacs, modeline

Is there a way to get some elements truncated in the (excellent) Emacs Powerline?  I'm thinking, in particular, at the `which-func-mode` section in the default mode line. It'd be good to see only the first N characters of a function name or section name (when in Org mode), N to be defined.

A side question is: can we simply get components being disabled (that is, not displayed) if the frame is too narrow (80 chars wide, for example)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can customize `which-func-format` accordingly, e.g.:

```lisp
(setq which-func-format
      `("["
        (:propertize (:eval (my-which-func-current))
                     local-map ,which-func-keymap
                     face which-func
                     mouse-face mode-line-highlight
                     help-echo "mouse-1: go to beginning\n\
mouse-2: toggle rest visibility\n\
mouse-3: go to end")
        "]")
      )
```

Where `my-which-func-current` is a function that truncates the current function name accordingly:

```lisp
(defun my-which-func-current ()
  (let ((current (gethash (selected-window) which-func-table)))
    (if current
        (truncate-string-to-width current 20 nil nil "…")
      which-func-unknown)))
```

This approach works with the standard mode line, and with any mode line extension package that supports standard mode line data.  I know that Smart Mode Line does, but I am not sure of Powerline.  I don't use either of these packages.

Comment: @user3341592 Your question inspired me to write a [small blog post](http://flycheck.readthedocs.org/en/latest/changes.html#apr-13-2013) about this topic.

Comment: May I ask what `which-func-keymap` is? When I loaded the given code, I got a `Symbol's value as variable is void: which-func-keymap` error. I tried to replace it with `nil` but then this does not seem to work. Thanks still for the effort. :)